# When I am running flutter project I am getting exception stating No toolchain found

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

1 warning
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-7.1.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:stripDevDebugDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevDebug'... Done                    156.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you add  project gradle file here?

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Comment: rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Try this:

Update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' to classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0" in android/build.gradle

Change distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' to classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0" in android/build.gradle Change distributionUrl=services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. –
Yas

By doing this i got my output

Answer (score 0):

This is common error. you can just clear the gradle cache.

> cd android
> ./gradlew clean

--> Update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' to classpath
"com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0" in android/build.gradle

--> Change distributionUrl=services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-
all.zip in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties